# F# selection sort on list of random integers

Tags: list, sorting, random, f#

I am new to F# and trying to figure out some basics but am stumbling along slowly.  In the code below I am trying to generate a list of random integers and then sorting it.

```
let randomNumberList count =
    let r = System.Random()
    List.init count (fun _ -> r.Next(100))

let rec selectionSort l = function
    | [] -> []
    | l -> let min = List.min l in
           let rest = List.filter (fun i -> i <> min) l in
           let sortedList = selectionSort rest in
           min :: sortedList
sortedList = selectionSort l

let unsortedList = randomNumberList 10
printfn "%A" unsortedList
printfn "%A" sortedList
```

So two things...one is the error I'm getting:

```
stdin(515,19): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'a list    
but here has type
    'a list -> 'a list
```

The other is with the random number list.  It works, but I want the numbers generated to be less than 100, instead of the massive values I'm getting now.

Thanks for your patience and help!

Comment: genRandomNumbers is undeclared when you call it.  Did something get lost in your copy/paste?  Also, "let rec selectoinSort l = function | [] ..." is busted as well.

Comment: yeah the genRandomNumbers was a typo.  can you show me how to fix the selectionSort function?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, there is no need for `l` in `let rec selectionSort`. Fixed code:

```
let randomNumberList count =
    let r = System.Random()
    List.init count (fun _ -> r.Next(100))

let rec selectionSort = function
    | [] -> []
    | l -> let min = List.min l in
           let rest = List.filter (fun i -> i <> min) l in
           let sortedList = selectionSort rest in
           min :: sortedList

let unsortedList = randomNumberList 10
let sortedList = selectionSort unsortedList
printfn "%A" unsortedList
printfn "%A" sortedList
System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Explanation:

```
let vname = function
   | ... -> ...
   | ... -> ...
```

is the short form of

```
let vname arg = match arg with
   | ... -> ...
   | ... -> ...
```

Comment: It's not going to be tail recursive either way :). The last thing you are doing in your function is calling (::), not selectionSort. Have a look at the generated IL.